# How to pthread_kill synchronously?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, signals

I am starting a bunch of joinable worker threads and `main()` waits for them to completed with `pthread_join()`. However, a user may hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the terminal before the worker threads have completed their task. My understanding is that any thread could get the signal so all my worker threads call `pthread_sigmask()` on start up and block `SIGINT` (the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> signal). This causes the signal to be copied to other threads and `main()`. This way I know that at least `main()` will get definitely the signal.

I have defined a signal handler function on `main()` so that `main()` gets the signal and can kill all the worker threads and free their resources from one place. The problem is that this happens asynchronously. I call `pthread_kill()` from `main()` and then try to `free()` resources the worker thread is using and it's still running because the signal is dispatched asynchronously.

If I call `pthread_kill(SIGTERM, ...)` from `main()` to kill the thread `main()` gets killed too and `do_thread_cleanup(i)` is never called:

```
int main () {

    signal (SIGINT, signal_handler);

    for (i = 0; i < num_thd; i++) {
        pthread_create(thread_init, ...);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num_thd; i++) {
        pthread_join(...);
    }

    return 0;
}

void signal_handler(int signal) {
    for (i = 0; i < num_thd; i++) {
        pthread_kill(pthread_t, SIGINT);
        pthread_join(pthread_t, ...);
        do_thread_cleanup(i);  // Calls functions like free() and close()
    }
}

void thread_init() {
    sigset_t sigset;
    sigemptyset(&sigset);
    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGINT);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, NULL);
    do_stuff_in_a_loop();
}
```

How can I send `SIGKILL` to a thread without `main()` receiving that signal and killing itself? Alternatively, how can I wait for the thread to exit?

Having read the other SO posts the talk about using `pthread_cleanup_push()` and `pthread_cleanup_pop()` but that doesn't allow me to check form one central place that all threads are killed and their resources released.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can’t; but you can do something close.

Free(), malloc() and thus all paths leading to them are not signal safe; so you can’t call them from a signal handler.  It is rare that these functions would notice the signal (re)entry, so unpredictable behaviour is the likely result.

A good pattern is to have the main thread notice signals have occurred, and perform the processing for them within it.  You can do this, safely, by having the main thread employ a pthread_cond_t,pthread_mutex_t pair to watch a counter, and have the signal handler use the same pair to update the counter and notify the change.

Thus the main thread can treat signals as simple inputs to transition between states, such as Normal/SIGINT -> Quitting, Quitting/SIGALRM -> HardStop.
Free() is probably a bit heavy-handed, as it can cause your program to make sporadic memory references, which may be exploitable as an attack surface.